# Error JQuery promise: Was ist das?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following Intellisense in Visual Studio (`/// <reference path="jquery-2.0.3.js" />`)

[image]

what is this "error" promise?

The comment is the same as the documented [fail](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/) promise.
But I didn't find [any reference](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) of the error promise.... however, it seems that both *error* and *fail* does the same thing. (both works)...

Comment: It's a deprecated method of jquery's XHR, not a deferred's one. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ ctrl+f for "Deprecation Notice"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`error` is mapped to `fail` in jQuery XHR objects for backwards compatibility.

From [the source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/cb37994d76afb45efc3b606546349ed4e695c053/src/ajax.js#L500):

```
jqXHR.error = jqXHR.fail;
```

Comment: Of course. What else would you expect in that Intellisense comment?

Comment: I expected it to be like in the online documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/